# Count ocurrece of words and show it

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following file , fichero1.txt

```
Ana Rojo
Luis Verde
Victoria Azul
Luis Amarillo
Luis Verde
```

In the file there are repeated lines. I have to get to get a list of all the combinations (as well as the number of times they are repeated) of the name "Luis" with each of the different colors. In the previous example, the output of the command or commands should be:

I tried this code:

```
cat "fichero1.txt" | grep "Luis" | sort | uniq -cd | sort -r
```

but it's not working correctly, I only obtain

```
2 Luis Verde
```

The correct, expected output would be

```
2 Luis Verde
1 Luis Amarillo
```

Comment: Do your files actually have empty lines between all content lines, or did you paste them incorrectly?

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: is a problem about pasting here the input, there are no empty lines

Comment: @Cyrus I have updated it with my code

Comment: I suggest: `grep Luis file | sort -r | uniq -c`

Comment: What is the output of `cat "fichero1.txt" | grep "Luis"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the -d option on uniq you only ask for duplicate lines, therefore Luis Amarillo is not a valid result.

```
grep Luis fichero1.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -r
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

With gawk

```
gawk '
BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"}
$1=="Luis"{a[$0]++}
END{for(i in a)print a[i] OFS i}
' fichero1.txt
```